# Format/purpose for bits of assembly?

Tags: assembly, byte, bit

```
.DATA
number1 DWORD   ?
```

What is the question mark for? And this statement reserves 32 bits of memory. number1 is the name of the reserved space, correct?

```
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number", 0
```

I don't understand why it is a byte, that quote has 17 characters, I don't see how that can fit into 8 bits

```
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
```

To my understanding this statement reserves 40 bytes of memory and names it string. I think the 40 bytes are initialized with question marks.

Comment: the ? is just a placeholder.  the other two it is similar to saying unsigned char in C (or char) a string of bytes or 40 bytes of dont care what you init it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
number1 DWORD   ?
```

The question mark means the memory is not initialized.

```
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number", 0
```

The characters in the quote as well as the `0` at the end form a sequence of initialization values. It's like using `18 DUP ?` but with initial values also.

```
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
```

This reserves space for an uninitialized string of 40 bytes.

Comment: So, ? means not initialized? If I replaced the question mark with a character, such as a period or the letter 'A', it will be initialized with that character? I don't understand how prompt1 reserves a byte but is bigger than a byte.

Comment: Yes if you replace the question mark with a character or byte literal, it will be initialized with that value. The `BYTE` data type for `prompt1` says that is the element data type of the sequence. You could also do `var DWORD 0, 1, 2, 3` for instance to create an array of dword values initialized with those values.